# howto adapt onEdit function to fire for specific value

Tags: function, google-sheets

In an 'onEdit' function, all examples that I find in this forum or elswhere contain the same (or similar) line to define the source, like:

```
if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks updates in column E
```

I cannot find how to adapt this, but I want my onEdit function to fire only if the column is set to a specific value:

```
if value of column E is set to "done" then perform rest of the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 5 && e.value.toLowerCase() === 'done')
    Logger.log('Todo');
}
```

See [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with following script:

```
    function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "TaskBoard" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet; "TaskBoard"
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks updates in column B
     var cellContent = r.getValue();
     if (cellContent == 'Done')
     {
         var nextCell = r.offset(0, 4);  //offset to same row, and column F; B+4
         if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
         {
           var time = new Date();
           time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "CET", "yyyy-MM-dd");
           nextCell.setValue(time);
         }
     }
   };
 };
}
```